# Using an IF statement in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have a user defined function and I want to do a select and choose a column based on whether or not it is bigger or small than another.

For example:

```
Select
   t.A, t.B
From
  Table t
Where
  if(t.A <= t.B) then
    use t.A
  else
    use t.B
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it that you anticipate an if in a where would do? What does `use` mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN t.A <= t.B
    THEN t.A 
    ELSE t.B 
  END  AS Smaller
FROM Table t
```

Answer (score 1):

No! But you can use a `case` statement

```
Select
   t.A, t.B
From
   Table t
Where
   (case when t.A <= t.B then t.A ELSE t.B END) = SomeValue
```

or if the smaller column is required in the select statement only then

```
Select
   (case when t.A <= t.B then t.A ELSE t.B END) as column
From
   Table t
```

**NOTE**
I haven't used pervasive sql before, but a quick googlez reveals that the case statement was added in version 9.x??

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want?

```
SELECT MIN(t.A, t.B) AS SmallestAOrB FROM Table t
```